# Easiest way to return coordinates within dictionary in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, coordinates

I have multiple .csv files with a 'location' column that contains a dictionary with coordinates along with other variables. I'm struggling to call this dictionary on its own. I either get the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` or `NaN`.

My `data` variable is the .csv files converted to a pandas dataframe.

My `df` is just the column `location` from `data` and looks like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(loc, orient='index')
df

                                             0
0   {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [16.835441, ...
1   {'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255...
2   {'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255...
3   {'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255...
4   {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [16.835441, ...
```

which goes on for 800 rows for 10 .csv files.

Here are two ways I have tried so far.

```
import re
coords = []
for row in df[0]:
    try:
        coords.append.re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]',s)
    except:
        coords.append(np.NaN)
```

which returns

```
                                                 0      coords
0   {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [16.835441, ...    NaN
1   {'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255...         NaN
2   {'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255...         NaN
3   {'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255...         NaN
```

Or I try this: `data['location'].map(lambda v:v['coordinates'])` and get the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`.

What's wrong with either of my two methods? Or is there just a much simpler way to do this?

*An edit*: An even better solution would return two columns: 'xcoord' and 'ycoord'.

Here's an example version of the .csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c01scfe0jmszfuz/test.csv?dl=0

Comment: Better post a small fragment of your CSV file, because the error is likely to by your choice of reading a CSV. I'm sceptical about it because in `df` the rows contain different data structure, which is a bad sign.

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyPogrebnyak. I've added a link with the csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import json

doc = """_id,created,location,public,time_stamp,updated
53a1f3g44rf7a33ffgh43hh,8/12/16 6:55,"{'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255], 'type': 'Point'}",TRUE,6/3/16 23:30,6/3/16 2:55
53a1f3g44rf7a33ffgh43hh,8/13/16 6:55,"{'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255], 'type': 'Point'}",TRUE,6/4/16 23:30,6/4/16 2:55
53a1f3g44rf7a33ffgh43hh,8/14/16 6:55,"{'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255], 'type': 'Point'}",TRUE,6/5/16 23:30,6/5/16 2:55
53a1f3g44rf7a33ffgh43hh,8/15/16 6:55,"{'coordinates': [16.835441, 97.292495255], 'type': 'Point'}",TRUE,6/6/16 23:30,6/6/16 2:55
53a1f3g44rf7a33ffgh43hh,8/16/16 6:55,"{'coordinates': [10.835441, 87.292495255], 'type': 'Point'}",TRUE,6/7/16 23:30,6/7/16 2:55"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(doc))

def as_tuple(s):
    return json.loads(s.replace('\'','\"'))['coordinates']

def get_coord(x, pos):
    return as_tuple(x)[pos]    

df.coord0 = df.location.apply(get_coord, args=[0])
df.coord1 = df.location.apply(get_coord, args=[1])

assert df.coord0.iloc[-1] == 10.835441
```

Comment: Shouldn't `df.location[0]` in `as_tuple` be replaced by `s` ?

Comment: @Evgeny your code works. Curious about your reply to Blake.

Comment: @BlakeRegalia - indeed it should be the way you say, thanks for spotting the bug

Comment: I liked this solution. If you want, check out another one of my questions that I haven't gotten a good answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460594/sum-set-of-values-from-pandas-dataframe-within-certain-time-frame/46461461?noredirect=1#comment79878551_46461461.

Comment: The one at link provided is less intriguing, more of a debugging / data structure exercise. It would have attracted better answeres if you narrowed it down to a cleaner MWE, pointing exactly to one problem of counting number of date entries to intervals. This would have made it  more fun to answer.