# How to aggregate stats in one dataframe based on filtering values in another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, average

I have 2 dataframes. rdf is the reference dataframe I am trying to use to define the interval (top and bottom) to calculate an average between (all of the depths between this interval), but use ldf to actually run that calculation since it contains the values. rdf defines the top and bottom for each id number an average should be run for. There are multiple intervals for each id.

rdf is formatted as such:

```
ID   Top    Bottom 
1    2010   3000
1    4300   4500
1    4550   5000
1    7100   7700
2    3200   4100
2    4120   4180
2    4300   5300
2    5500   5520
3    2300   2380
3    3200   4500
```

ldf is fromated as such:

```
ID   Depth(ft)    Value1   Value2   Value3 
1    2000         45       .32      423
1    2000.5       43       .33      500
1    2001         40       .12      643
1    2001.5       28       .10      20
1    2002         40       .10      34
1    2002.5       23       .11      60
1    2003         34       .08      900
1    2003.5       54       .04      1002
2    2000         40       .28      560
2    2000         38       .25      654
...
3    2000         43       .30      343
```

I want to use rdf to define the top and bottom of the interval to calculate the average for Value1, Value2, and Value3. I would also like to have a count documented as well (not all of the values between the intervals necessarily exist, so it could be less than the difference of Bottom - Top). This will then modify rdf to make a new file:

new_rdf is formatted as such:

```
ID   Top    Bottom   avgValue1   avgValue2   avgValue3  ThicknessCount(ft)
1    2010   3000     54          .14         456        74
1    4300   4500     23          .18         632        124    
1    4550   5000     34          .24         780        111
1    7100   7700     54          .19         932        322
2    3200   4100     52          .32         134        532
2    4120   4180     16          .11         111        32
2    4300   5300     63          .29         872        873
2    5500   5520     33          .27         1111       9
3    2300   2380     63          .13         1442       32
3    3200   4500     37          .14         1839       87
```

I've been going back and forth on the best way to do this. I tried mimicking this time series example: [Sum set of values from pandas dataframe within certain time frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460594/sum-set-of-values-from-pandas-dataframe-within-certain-time-frame)

but it doesn't seem translatable:

```
import pandas as pd

Top = rdf['Top']
Bottom = rdf['Bottom']
Depths = ldf['DEPTH']

def get_depths(x):
    n = ldf[(ldf['DEPTH']>x['top']) & (ldf['DEPTH']<x['bottom'])]
    return n['ID'].values[0],n['DEPTH'].sum()

test = pd.DataFrame({'top':Top, 'bottom':Bottom})
test[['ID','Value1']] = test.apply(lambda x : get_depths(x),1).apply(pd.Series)
```

I get `"TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str"`
And it works if I use the samples they made in the post, but it doesn't work with my data. I'm also hoping there's a more, simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit # 2A:**

Note:
*Sample DataFrame below is not exactly the same as posted in question*

Posting a new code here that does uses `Top` and `Bottom` from `rdf` to check for `DEPTH` in `ldf` to calculate `.mean()` for each group using `for-loop`. A `range_key` is created in `rdf` that is unique to each row, assuming that the DataFrame `rdf` does not have any duplicates.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
rdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],
    'Top': [2000,4300,4500,7100,3200,4120,4300,5500,2300,3200],
    'Bottom':[2500,4500,5000,7700,4100,4180,5300,5520,2380,4500]
})
ldf = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3],
    'DEPTH': [2000,2000.5,2001,2001.5,4002,4002.5,5003,5003.5,2000,2000,2000],
    'Value1':[45,43,40,28,40,23,34,54,40,38,43],
    'Value2':[.32,.33,.12,.10,.10,.11,.08,.04,.28,.25,.30],
    'Value3':[423,500,643,20,34,60,900,1002,560,654,343]
})

# Create a key for merge later
ldf['range_key'] = np.nan
rdf['range_key'] = np.linspace(1,rdf.shape[0],rdf.shape[0]).astype(int).astype(str)


# Flag each row for a range
for i in range(ldf.shape[0]):
    for j in range(rdf.shape[0]):
        d = ldf['DEPTH'][i]
        if (d>= rdf['Top'][j]) & (d<=rdf['Bottom'][j]):
            rkey = rdf['range_key'][j]
            ldf['range_key'][i]=rkey
            break;
ldf['range_key'] = ldf['range_key'].astype(int).astype(str) # Convert to string


# Calculate mean for groups
ldf_mean = ldf.groupby(['ID','range_key']).mean().reset_index()
ldf_mean = ldf_mean.drop(['DEPTH'], axis=1)


# Merge into 'rdf'
new_rdf = rdf.merge(ldf_mean, on=['ID','range_key'], how='left')
new_rdf = new_rdf.drop(['range_key'], axis=1)
new_rdf
```

Output:

```
    ID  Top Bottom  Value1  Value2  Value3
0   1   2000    2500    39.0    0.2175  396.5
1   1   4300    4500    NaN NaN NaN
2   1   4500    5000    NaN NaN NaN
3   1   7100    7700    NaN NaN NaN
4   2   3200    4100    NaN NaN NaN
5   2   4120    4180    NaN NaN NaN
6   2   4300    5300    NaN NaN NaN
7   2   5500    5520    NaN NaN NaN
8   3   2300    2380    NaN NaN NaN
9   3   3200    4500    NaN NaN NaN
```

**Edit # 1:**

Code below seems to work. Added an `if-statement` to the `return` from the code posted in question above. Not sure if this is what you were looking to get. It calculates the `.sum()`. The first value in `rdf` is changed to a lower the range to match the data in `ldf`.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
rdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3],
    'Top': [2000,4300,4500,7100,3200,4120,4300,5500,2300,3200],
    'Bottom':[2500,4500,5000,7700,4100,4180,5300,5520,2380,4500]
})
ldf = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3],
    'DEPTH': [2000,2000.5,2001,2001.5,2002,2002.5,2003,2003.5,2000,2000,2000],
    'Value1':[45,43,40,28,40,23,34,54,40,38,43],
    'Value2':[.32,.33,.12,.10,.10,.11,.08,.04,.28,.25,.30],
    'Value3':[423,500,643,20,34,60,900,1002,560,654,343]
})

##### Code from the question  (copy-pasted here)
Top = rdf['Top']
Bottom = rdf['Bottom']
Depths = ldf['DEPTH']

def get_depths(x):
    n = ldf[(ldf['DEPTH']>x['top']) & (ldf['DEPTH']<x['bottom'])]
    if (n.shape[0]>0):
        return n['ID'].values[0],n['DEPTH'].sum()
    

test = pd.DataFrame({'top':Top, 'bottom':Bottom})
test[['ID','Value1']] = test.apply(lambda x : get_depths(x),1).apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
test

    top  bottom   ID   Value1
0  2000    2500  1.0  14014.0
1  4300    4500  NaN      NaN
2  4500    5000  NaN      NaN
3  7100    7700  NaN      NaN
4  3200    4100  NaN      NaN
5  4120    4180  NaN      NaN
6  4300    5300  NaN      NaN
7  5500    5520  NaN      NaN
8  2300    2380  NaN      NaN
9  3200    4500  NaN      NaN
```

Comment: I keep getting this error:
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str

And I have tried a few times to change the datatype. I looked at the raw data and it's a float64

Comment: Could you post the code to create a sample DataFrame `rdf` and `ldf` that reproduces the TypeError. Because without that it is difficult to find the source of the error.

Comment: I don't think I can, it's pretty much what I posted so it may be how the .csv file is savving. That's okay for now I can figure it out eventually. I have another thing I noticed, the sum of Value one is not actually the sum of the values available. I also amended sum to mean() and I get 2002.0 as the average value. For Value1 the mean should be in the 40s, and the sum shouldn't be more than 500.

Comment: I've posted Edit # 2 that is a new code. May be this could help. It calculates the `mean`.

Comment: This is a lot closer, and I have been fiddling with this all day, but it's still not giving me the proper mean per interval. It's close. The result for Edit #2 should only have an average for 1, 2000, 2500. The others should actually still be blank since the sample I gave doesn't have values in those ranges (my bad). I'm having the same issue on  my larger dataset as well. It only seems to create a proper average for some ID/Interval combinations.

Comment: (1) The code Edit # 2A is updated accordingly. It now has only one row with values and others are blank as suggested (2) To look at other scenarios, it is difficult to account for those in the code without those specific edge cases in `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

### Sample data and imports

```py
import pandas
import numpy
import random

# dfr
rdata = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
         'Top': [2010, 4300, 4550, 7100, 3200, 4120, 4300, 5500, 2300, 3200],
         'Bottom': [3000, 4500, 5000, 7700, 4100, 4180, 5300, 5520, 2380, 4500]}

dfr = pd.DataFrame(rdata)

# display(dfr.head())
   ID   Top  Bottom
0   1  2010    3000
1   1  4300    4500
2   1  4550    5000
3   1  7100    7700
4   2  3200    4100

# df
np.random.seed(365)
random.seed(365)
rows = 10000
data = {'id': [random.choice([1, 2, 3]) for _ in range(rows)],
        'depth': [np.random.randint(2000, 8000) for _ in range(rows)],
        'v1': [np.random.randint(40, 50) for _ in range(rows)],
        'v2': np.random.rand(rows),
        'v3': [np.random.randint(20, 1000) for _ in range(rows)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(['id', 'depth'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# display(df.head())
   id  depth  v1        v2   v3
0   1   2004  48  0.517014  292
1   1   2004  41  0.997347  859
2   1   2006  42  0.278217  851
3   1   2006  49  0.570363   32
4   1   2009  43  0.462985  409
```

### Use each row of `dfr` to filter and extract stats from `df`

- There are plenty of answers on SO dealing with `"TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=float64 and str"`. The numeric columns need to be cleaned of any value that can't be converted to a numeric type.
- This code deals with using one dataframe to filter and return metrics for another dataframe.
- For each row in `dfr`:

  - Filter `df`
  - Aggregate the `mean` and `count` for `v1`, `v2` and `v3`
  - `.T` to transpose the `mean` and `count` rows to columns
  - Convert to a numpy array
  - Slice the array for the 3 means and append the array to the `v_mean`
  - Slice the array for the max count and append the value to `count`

    - They could be all the same, if there are no `NaNs` in the data
- Convert the list of arrays, `v_mean` to a dataframe, and join it to `dfr_new`
- Add `counts` a column in `dfr_new`

```py
v_mean = list()
counts = list()

for idx, (i, t, b) in dfr.iterrows():  # iterate through each row of dfr

    data = df[['v1', 'v2', 'v3']][(df.id == i) & (df.depth >= t) & (df.depth <= b)].agg(['mean', 'count']).T.to_numpy()  # apply filters and get stats
    v_mean.append(data[:, 0])  # get the 3 means
    counts.append(data[:, 1].max())  # get the max of the 3 counts; each column has a count, the count cound be different if there are NaNs in data


# copy dfr to dfr_new
dfr_new = dfr.copy()

# add stats values
dfr_new = dfr_new.join(pd.DataFrame(v_mean, columns=['v1_m', 'v2_m', 'v3_m']))
dfr_new['counts'] = counts

# display(dfr_new)
   ID   Top  Bottom    v1_mean   v2_mean     v3_mean  count
0   1  2010    3000  44.577491  0.496768  502.068266  542.0
1   1  4300    4500  44.555556  0.518066  530.968254  126.0
2   1  4550    5000  44.446281  0.538855  482.818182  242.0
3   1  7100    7700  44.348083  0.489983  506.681416  339.0
4   2  3200    4100  44.804040  0.487011  528.707071  495.0
5   2  4120    4180  45.096774  0.526687  520.967742   31.0
6   2  4300    5300  44.476980  0.529476  523.095764  543.0
7   2  5500    5520  46.000000  0.608876  430.500000   12.0
8   3  2300    2380  44.512195  0.456632  443.195122   41.0
9   3  3200    4500  44.554755  0.516616  501.841499  694.0
```

Comment: I get the error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)". My actual data has some "junk columns" that I'm keeping around in case the user finds it useful later on (each top and bottom depth has a name specifically). I think this is causing the error, since I think the i, t, b are assuming the first 3 columns in the database correct? Is there a way to make those iterations more specific?

Comment: @MineralDragon This is based on the sample data, so `dfr` should only contain the 3 expected columns. `dfr[['ID', 'Top', 'Bottom']].iterrows()`

Comment: Oh yes, this does work for the sample data perfectly, I get the proper results. I'm trying to use this on my larger dataset now which I didn't want to gunk up this ask with since it has several columns I'm not calculating from and was trying to get to the basics of the question. Is there a way to more specifically reference the columns or should I just clean out the dataframe of time to get the array to work? My bad, I didn't think it would cause a limitation, unfortunately I have been mostly working with df so far, trying to learn more.

Comment: @MineralDragon My last comment showed you how to select the specific 3 columns for iteration, and they need to be in the correct order. `dfr[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].iterrows()`